# notification beeper like fb in php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new in php and i want to know if there is a way to make this script to read from db all events from users and trigger a popup notification something like "John is like your photo" or "Maria is following you" something like that,similar like facebook beeper. Any help apreciated!
I have started with this codes:

Fetch PHP code:

```
        <?php
    //fetch-popup-notification.php;

    include("connect.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM notification_users WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $output = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $output .= '
     <div class="alert alert_default">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <p><strong>'.$row["subject"].'</strong>
       <small><em>'.$row["notification"].'</em></small>
      </p>
     </div>
     ';
    }

    echo $output;
    $update_query = "UPDATE notifications_users SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0";
mysqli_query($connect, $update_query);
    ?>
```

Ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

 setInterval(function(){
  load_last_notification();
 }, 6000);

 function load_last_notification()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"notificari/fetch-popup-notification.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('.notif-popup').html(data);
   }
  })
 }

});
  </script>
```

html:

```
<div id='alert_popover'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
     <div class='notif-popup'>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

> in DB i have: id | subject | notification | status

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do or what is not working more specifically?

Comment: ok and what did this attempt give you? Errors?  Unexpected result?  You seem to be on the right track, what is the issue?  Your question is "is there a way..."?  Yes there is :-)

Comment: I'm trying to figure'it out how to read from db and to get notified by a popup like facebook beeper if someone do something "like my photo" "if give's me a msg" or "following me" this script is a start..i guess..

Comment: Sounds like something better done with javascript. The javascript could make an ajax request to a php page every few minutes which is how the front-end of the app could decide when to show a notification.